# Join list of matrices using xtabs inside for() loop

Tags: r, matrix

Say we have a set of matrices of different dimensions, but with common row and column names. We would like to find the element-wise means of the matrices. `xtabs()` is a convenient function for this.

However, inside of `for()`, `as.table()` fails to recognize the expression calling each matrix. Creating a list of the matrices first and then calling each element of that list fails just the same.

MWE: Create matrices:

```
m1 <- matrix(1:9,nrow=3,ncol=3)
colnames(m1) <- c("A","B","C")
rownames(m1) <- c("A","B","C")
m2 <- matrix(10:18,nrow=3,ncol=3)
colnames(m2) <- c("A","B","C")
rownames(m2) <- c("A","B","C")
m3 <- matrix(19:22,nrow=2,ncol=2)
colnames(m3) <- c("A","B")
rownames(m3) <- c("A","B")
```

Use one of the matrices as a foundation to build from:

```
A <- m1
```

Join and find means:

```
for(i in 2:3){
  mat <- noquote(paste0("m", i))
  B   <- rbind(as.data.frame(as.table(A)), as.data.frame(as.table(mat)))
  A   <- xtabs(Freq ~ Var1 + Var2, aggregate(Freq ~ Var1 + Var2, B, mean))
}
```

The problem is with `as.table(mat)`, resulting in an error:

```
Error in as.table.default(mat) : cannot coerce to a table
```

This is just a working example, the real application repeats this over thousands of matrices with different naming conventions. Inserting `noquote(paste0("m", i))` directly into `as.table()` also fails.

Simply replacing `mat` with the matrix object directly works fine (i.e. `as.table(m2)`).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we need `get` to get the value from the string identifier object

```
for(i in 2:3){
    mat <- get(paste0("m", i))
    B   <- rbind(as.data.frame(as.table(A)), as.data.frame(as.table(mat)))
     A   <- xtabs(Freq ~ Var1 + Var2, aggregate(Freq ~ Var1 + Var2, B, mean))
}

A
#    Var2
#Var1     A     B     C
#   A 12.25 14.75 11.50
#   B 13.25 15.75 12.50
#   C  7.50 10.50 13.50
```

Comment: Thank you... ugh, sometimes these things escape me. Will accept momentarily.